# How to fetch all objects of a model in serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I'm using ActiveModelSerializer for a Rails API. On some controller inside index action I need to display all existing objects of class **Book**.

```
def index
  render json: { books: Book.all }
end
```

But I suppose this isn't the right way. To follow convention, I need to use serializer. So my question is how could I achieve this using serializer, so I could write something like this?

```
def index
  render json: { books: BookSerializer }
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you looking for something like `render json: @books, serializer: BookSerializer ` ??

Comment: or  `render json: Book.all, serializer: BookSerializer` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
def index
  books = Book.all
  render json: books, each_serializer: BookSerializer, root: books
end
```

*P.S. Beware though rendering all books will be slow. It's better to add pagination*

Comment: What if I have several models? Can this be done not only with objects of one model?

Comment: @BillyLogan you could create top level serializer. Here is an example https://gist.github.com/TheSmartnik/55c207dcdb7926dbfc5e59e1430b4914